# From javascript browser client-side to Postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I want to connect from the **client side / browser / javascript** to **PSQL**.

I know what you are going to say: "*This is unsafe*". And **I know**.

This is a small project with not a large scope. I made a "login" page where the user will enter their own postgres URI and connect to their own database.

The idea is:

- "You want to use the app?"
- go on heroku,
- make a free database,
- paste the URI,
- you're good to go.

Most likely, I will be the only user and that's fine.

So, I have a netlify client-side stack pure javascript with requirejs and I am looking for a js file I can load as a library to have basic wrapper to send SQL queries.

Is that possible ? From what I have read, it seems that it is not possible because of the kind of sockets that would need to be open. Is that true ? Please, someone tell me there is a solution :)

HTTP is TCP based, I don't see how it would be impossible to open a TCP socket to a database URL. right ?

Thanks !

Comment: See (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/List_of_drivers) for a list of client libraries.

Comment: @clamp , the only two JS one that I see are for nodejs , which means server-side, right ?

Comment: `psql` is the Postgresql client program, so you want to connect to `Postgresql`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver , i updated the title :)